# Why is ScaffoldState not working in Android Studio Kotlin with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I try to use a Scaffold in android studio with jetpack compose, but I can't use the scaffoldState in my project. Both in a @Composable Scaffold parameter and the rememberScaffoldState() method.

Here is my simple project:

```kotlin
package com.example.trainingtimer

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
            Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.trainingtimer'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.trainingtimer"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

}
```

I try to change the version of the dependency androidx.compose.material3:material3 to 1.0.0 but I doesn't change the result.

The scaffoldState it is deprecated?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scaffold` composable in Material 3 doesn't require `scaffoldState` anymore:

> The M2 ScaffoldState class no longer exists in M3 as it contains a drawerState parameter which is no longer needed. To show snackbars with the M3 Scaffold, use SnackbarHostState instead
> [Read more here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#:%7E:text=The%20M2%20ScaffoldState%20class%20no%20longer%20exists%20in%20M3%20as%20it%20contains%20a%20drawerState%20parameter%20which%20is%20no%20longer%20needed.%20To%20show%20snackbars%20with%20the%20M3%20Scaffold%2C%20use%20SnackbarHostState%20instead%3A)

Currently the Scaffold looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun Scaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarHost: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButtonPosition: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    contentWindowInsets: WindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets,
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I suspected as much. I was following an old tutorial to learn how to use the Scaffold composable. Looks like I'll have to find another tutorial.

Comment: It's ok to learn from old tutorials as long as they are explaining things right. Just search the documentations if something is different and you'll find the solution. @Thibaut_Esteve

Answer (score 1):

in material 3 we don't have Scaffold anymore so delete Scaffold and it will work

Comment: The answer is not correct as Material 3 has Scaffold.